# Mimic process.argv

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I'm passed a command line argument string that I want to turn into an array.

Typically, I can do something like:

```
node log_argv.js --howdy="boop \"\' dkjf roop" what -jump -gop=30
```

Where log_argv.js:

```
console.log(process.argv.slice(2));
```

And the response is:

```
[ '--howdy=boop "\\\' dkjf roop', 'what', '-jump', '-gop=30' ]
```

How might I mimic process.argv in this case if I am given the argv string in my script and I can't actually use process.argv? For instance, I might have a script:

```
var arg_string = '--howdy="boop \"\' dkjf roop" what -jump -gop=30'
var arg_array = parse_arguments(arg_string);
console.log(arg_array);
```

And the result should be like above, ie:

```
[ '--howdy=boop "\\\' dkjf roop', 'what', '-jump', '-gop=30' ]
```

The closest thing I've seen is this: https://github.com/mccormicka/string-argv. But given the argument string above, I get a different result than process.argv.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a string in the same way bash does by using a `shellwords` port.
There is a javascript version of ruby's shellwords module called `shellwords` on npm (https://github.com/jimmycuadra/shellwords).

`npm install shellwords`

Then in your code:

```
var shellwords = require('shellwords');
shellwords.split("foo 'bar baz'");
// ["foo", "bar baz"]
```

You can test it out here: https://api.blockspring.com/jtokoph/8c997e4dd22157e7d07a23123f08fc0d